# Bulk Updating colums in a table in Java in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

```
Id status  
789  1    
769  0   
234  1
```

Updating the status values of id's to

```
Id status  
789  0    
769  0   
234  1
```

Instead of using **select query, modelservice** and saving one by one, 
Can a bulk update be done with **Update-Query** or **Impex Insert_Update** in **JAVA**

Comment: Question is not clear. I think you are looking for something like this `modelService.saveAll(models)`

Comment: If you have your data in CSV format then you can configure it using [Hot Folder](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Hot+Folder) as well.

Comment: Impex just uses the Hybris ModelService when it executes and so does not solve this problem i'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybris does not currently have an effective bulk updating feature - ModelService.saveAll() does not combine multiple updates into one SQL statement to execute.

I have personally hit this limitation many times when a large number of records need to be updated regularly.

I have spoken to the Hybris core platform team about this in the past but they do not seem keen to address it.

If I have a situation where I need to update a large number of records (hundreds of thousands or more) regularly I tend to store that data in a table outside of the Hybris data model and access it using plain JDBC - not terribly elegant, but not too bad as long as you wrap it the DAO layer.

Taking it a step further, you may want to consider a NoSQL approach using something like MongoDB to store these records, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: What do you do about caching? Do you expect this data to be accessed in the DB every time? Do you emit cache invalidation messages?

Just today i was getting 1000 updates a second via impex. Is this not effective?

Comment: 1000 updates a second is pretty damn good! Was that updates or inserts? Does the entity you are inserting have any/many relations?

In my suggestion you bypass the Hybris cache entirely, so yes any queries go direct to DB - it may be wise to add caching, but that depends on your use case.

I used this approach when I had millions of records to update every night.